# How do I find the x values for which my series converge? One has a square root in it. Can I use ratio test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, ratio

I have to find the x values for which it converges.

They are potency series so I just have do use the series without x

a) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \sqrt{n}}{3^{n}}(x+3)^{n}$

For a) I don't know if I can use the ratio test for it?

Because it can be 0 for some n?

If I want to use the square root test I am literally stuck at the start.

Our profs told us that we have to be careful and can just use ratio tests if the series will never become 0

b) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n}}{n \sqrt{n}}(x-2)^{n}$

Comment: Look at power series and radius of convergence.

Comment: I get what to do but now for this case. I get stuck at the ratio test for this one or the square root test. That's the problem I am facing. I get $\frac{n*\sqrt{n}}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}}$  Now I don't know how to go further for this case. There is basically nothing I can do.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio test shows that the series converges for $|x+3| <3$ or $-6 <x<0$. [ $\lim \frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}=3(x+3)$ because $\frac n {n+1} \to 1, \frac {\sqrt n} {\sqrt {n+1}} \to 1, \frac {3^{n+1}} {3^{n}}=3$ and $\lim \frac {(x+3)^{n+1}} {(x+3)^{n}} =x+3$].  The series divers for $x=-6$ and $x=0$ since the general term does  not tend to $0$. Recall that $\sum a_n$ cannot converge unless $a_n \to 0$. The radius of convergence is $3$.

b) is similar.

Comment: I get to this with ratio test : $\frac{n*\sqrt{n}}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+1}}$

Comment: @Rapiz You forgot $|\frac {(x+3)^{n+1}} {(x+3)^{n}}|$. Note that $\frac  n {n+1} \to 1$ and $\frac  {\sqrt n} {\sqrt {n+1} }\to 1$.

Comment: Why did you use x+3? I thought it is not used for potency series ?  In my lectures they states just to test an not (x-x)^n

Comment: I got  $\frac{3^{n+1}*(n*\sqrt{n})}{3^n(n+1)*\sqrt{n+1}}$

Comment: You are applying ratio test to $\sum a_n$ where $a_n=\frac {n\sqrt n}{3^{n}} (x+3)^{n}$. You have to calculate $\frac  {a_{n+1}} {a_n}$ from this formula for $a_n$.

Comment: Well I don't know why but in my lecture videos literally every time we want to find x values for potency series we ignore the term with (x+x0)^n  to find the convergence radius They cite Cauchy-Hadamard with the an*(x-x0)^k

Comment: @Rapiz We are talking about two different things. If you want to apply ratio test you cannot ignore $(x+3)^{n}$. But if you are using a formula for the radius of convergence then $(x+3)^{n}$ does not come into the picture. Since you mentioned ratio test in your question I gave an answer based on ratio test.

Comment: Well then sorry for this. I thought I have mentioned this. I want to calculate the radius of convergence. So what would be the way to go further than my weird equation? ^^

Comment: Radius of convergence can be calulated using ratio test also and that is what I have already done. The series converges if $|x+3| <3$ and diverges if $|x+3| >3$. This implies that the radius of convergence is $3$.

Comment: So you used the whole term right? And I can do this for such exercises?

Comment: How did you get the result?